# How to correctly set up foreground notifications using react-native-firebase v5?

Tags: firebase, react-native, push-notification, react-native-firebase

We have a react-native app that runs its notifications through FCM with the following environment:

```
  react-native: 0.59.10,
  react-native-firebase: 5.5.6
```

All the configs have been set up, certificates provisioned, etc. Until the very present time, notifications have been working like a clock, but recently we stopped receiving notifications in the foreground.

Here's the `NotificationsManager` code:

```
import firebase from 'react-native-firebase';

const CHANNEL = 'default';

...

const localNotificationListener = React.useRef();
const notificationOpenListener = React.useRef();
const onTokenRefreshListener = React.useRef();

const receiveForegroundPN = (n) => {
    const notification = new firebase.notifications.Notification()
      .setNotificationId(n.notificationId)
      .setTitle(n.title)
      .setSubtitle(n.subtitle)
      .setBody(n.body)
      .setData(n.data);

    if (Platform.OS === 'android') {
      notification
        .android.setChannelId(CHANNEL)
        .android.setSmallIcon('ic_launcher');
    }
    firebase.notifications().displayNotification(notification);
  };

React.useEffect(() => {
    const channel = new firebase.notifications.Android.Channel(
      CHANNEL,
      'Bank Notifications',
      firebase.notifications.Android.Importance.Max,
    ).setDescription('*****');

    firebase.notifications().android.createChannel(channel);

    localNotificationListener.current = firebase.notifications().onNotification(receiveForegroundPN);
    notificationOpenListener.current = firebase.notifications().onNotificationOpened(openNotification);

    onTokenRefreshListener.current = firebase.messaging().onTokenRefresh((fcmToken) => {
      registerToken({
        device_token: fcmToken,
      });
    });

    runFlow();

    return () => {
      localNotificationListener.current();
      notificationOpenListener.current();
      onTokenRefreshListener.current();
    };
  }, []);
```

Notifications work just fine on both platforms while the app is in the background, but never show when the app is in the foreground.

I've tried setting `show_on_foreground: "true"`, but that didn't help. Actually, I tried logging anything in the `receiveForegroundPN` method but it was never called, i.e. it looks like notifications are never received from firebase when app is running.

What might be the issue here and possible solutions to make notifications work?

### Update

All of a sudden, within the hour of posting this, iOS started to receive foreground notifications. Android still doesn't work, yet it used to.

Answer (score 1):

I am having a similar issue as well.. ,
The onNotification method doesn't get trigerred so i tried the onMessage method instead which seems to work for foreground.

```js
 firebase.messages().onMessage(msg => {
  // ... your code here
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Iterating on Amr's answer.

As per [documentation](https://rnfirebase.io/messaging/usage#foreground-state-messages), you must hook into firebase's callbacks to get notified when a push notification is received in foreground.
From that point you can decide how to handle the message.

1. The simplest way is to display an alert `Alert.alert('A new FCM message arrived!', JSON.stringify(remoteMessage));` or
2. You can use another library to display a local notification. Here is an example using `react-native-notifications` library:

```
// Just call the hook in some root component that's always present

export const useDisplayRemoteNotifications: () => void = () => {
  useEffect(() => {
    return messaging().onMessage(async remoteMessage => {
      Notifications.postLocalNotification({
        title: remoteMessage.notification?.title || '',
        body: remoteMessage.notification?.body || '',
        fireDate: dayjs().add(1, 'second').toDate(), // one second later
      });
    });
  }, []);
};
```

Comment: any method using which we can get notification in the tray when app is open, running.

Comment: I think you are asking for a "foreground notification". Does my suggestion work for you?

Comment: yes foreground notifications, FCM doesnt support foreground, but react-push-notifications does support foreground and it does work, but I cant find anyway to handle a click on that, it provides us with onNotification handler but that fires when a notification arrives or when clicked, is dere a way to fire only when notification is clicked.

Comment: Don't have the relevant code available at the moment, but it seems that you can use `Notifications.events().registerNotificationOpened` from `react-native-notifications`. https://wix.github.io/react-native-notifications/docs/notifications-events

Comment: Im able to achieve the click in background as well as quit state but in foreground I don't see notification in the tray using FCM, I dont think this will either work

Comment: I'm afraid I won't be of much help. That was an old project that I don't have an access to anymore so can't look it up